# Dynamically add/remove new input to form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, input

So I am a beginner and as the title says I want to be able to; on the click of a button, allow the user to add another input field to my form. I would also like to be able to remove this.

The use of the form is adding students to a student group, which I will then be storing in my database.

my form example:

```
<form name="addstudents" id="addstudents" method="post" action="add_students.php">
<table><tr><td>Student:</td><td>
<input type='text' name="1" size='20'></td><td><input type="button" id="add" value="+">    
</td><td><input type="button" id="remove" value="-"></td>
</table></form>
```

However from what I have been looking at there are different suggestions such as using a clone() function or Jquery appendto().

which is the best method for doing so?

thanks

Comment: you don't need table for this. you might also try using labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').append('<input ...'); //take care of appending valid DOM elements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create the input element
var $el = $('<input>')//Set the attribute that you want
                      .attr('id','inputID')
                      .attr('readonly',true);
//And append it to the form
$('#addstudents').append($el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember you also can remove any DOM from your form just find the appropiate jquery selector

```
$('form > input:last').remove(); // to remove last input
```

check this working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LGtVE/) that a made on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to help you with this

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript, I already answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220860/multiple-dynamic-selections/5358181#5358181).  Just uses plain JavaScript to edit the HTML of the page.  Hope this helps!